# Music player in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: button, actionscript, playback

I already added a stop button with autoplay but I need to make it so when you click the button again after you had stopped it, the music starts playing.

Source code:

```
var music:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("calmingsong.mp3"));
var sc:SoundChannel = music.play();

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMusic);

function stopMusic(e:Event):void
{
sc.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to play the sound over from the beginning, just call the `Sound` object's `play()` method again (you get a new `SoundChannel` object when you do this).

If you'd like to resume playing the sound at the point where the user stopped it, you'll need to add additional variables to store the current "playback state"... Something like this:

```
var music:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("calmingsong.mp3"));
var sc:SoundChannel = music.play();
var startPosition:Number = 0;
var isPlaying = true; // default to true cause you auto play...

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, togglePlayback);

function togglePlayback(e:Event):void
{
    if (isPlaying)
    {
        startPosition = sc.position;
        sc.stop();
        isPlaying = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sc = music.play(startPosition);
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much however I'm getting one compiler error - any idea how to fix it? "1152: A conflict with inherited definition flash.display.MovieClip.isPlaying in namespace public.

Comment: Yes, poor choice of the variable name on my part, as a MovieClip already has a variable named "isPlaying". Just change that to some other name like "playbackStarted" or whatever :)